# Dynamically infer prop type based on config

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

Is it possible to dynamically infer the correct prop type based on component type provided in same prop?

Currently I have component which correctly infers the expected props based on the provided component type.

```
export interface IFieldTypeProps<TComponent extends React.ComponentType<any>> {
  type: TComponent;
  props: React.ComponentProps<TComponent>;
}

export function Field<TComponent extends React.ComponentType<any>>({
  type: Component,
  props,
}: IFieldTypeProps<TComponent>) {
  return <Component {...props} />;
}

<Field type={TextField} props={{ required: true, label: "First Name" }} />; // expected prop type inferred based on type prop
```

I want to do do something similar using strictly config and no JSX. Is this possible?

Example:

```
const fields = [
  {
    type: TextField,
    props: { required: true, label: "First Name" }, // Typecheck not working should infer props based on type above
  }, 
];

const Form = () => {
  return (
    fields.map((field) => {
      <field.type {...field.props}/>
    })
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way which take advantage of function parametters inferance to stay as close a a pure definition way but adding Strong typed vérification:

```
    type Field<Props> = {
        Component: React.ComponentType<Props> | React.FC<Props>,
        props: Props,
    };
    
    const createField = <Props, >(
        Component: React.ComponentType<Props> | React.FC<Props>,
        props: Props,
    ): Field<Props> => ({
            Component,
            props,
        });
    
    const fields = [
        createField(
            TextField,
            { required: true, label: "First Name" },
        ),
        createField(
            TextField,
            { required: true, label: "Last Name" },
        ),
    ];
    
    export const Form = ({
    }) => (
        fields.map(({ Component, props }) => <Component {...props}/>)
    );
```